# Image preview in child page using JQuery not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, filereader

I want to preview image in a div when user browse the image while sign up using JQuery.

Below is child page names SignUp.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="phForChildPage" runat="server">
<asp:Table runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" BorderColor="Yellow" BorderStyle="Dotted" BorderWidth="2">
<asp:TableRow runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                    <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fuUserPicture" CssClass="ui-corner-all" />
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                        <div id="imageHolder"></div>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
</asp:Content>
```

JQuery code in JavaScript file.

```
// for image preview
$(function () {
    $("#phForChildPage_fuUserPicture").on('change', function () {
        if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
            var imageHolder = $("#phForChildPage_imageHolder");
            imageHolder.empty();
            //make new instance of file reader
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $("<img />", {
                    "src": e.target.result,
                    "class": "thumb-image",
                    "width": "200px",
                    "height": "200px"
                }).appendTo(imageHolder);
            }
            imageHolder.show();
            reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[0]);
        }
        else {
            alert("This browser does not support File Reader");
        }
    })
});
```

I check my JQuery works. All fine. Just Image is not shown in div. Please help.

Comment: did you check e.target.result in console?

Comment: Yes I check on console. There is no error.

Comment: I know there is no error but did u you get the image source bcoz you have assigned e.target.result in src key.

Comment: Is the debugger enter the function `$("#phForChildPage_fuUserPicture").on('change'` at all? Are you sure that the server render the if `fuUserPicture` as `phForChildPage_fuUserPicture`? Can you show us the output html of this `asp.net` code?

Comment: Banik, I don't know how to check what is in e.target.result because VS do not debug JavaScript code. I see in alert and it shows like this data:image/jpeg.... and other. I paste there but it is too long. I just want to preview image before saving data into server. Please help

Comment: Mosh Feu, yes control enter in `$("#phForChildPage_fuUserPucture").on("change",function(){...})` and server render `phForChildPage_fuUserPicture` instead of `fuUserPicture` because the code is in `ContentPlaceHolder` in child page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the mistake in your original code. You are using $('#phForChildPage_imageHolder') to access div but the fact is div id is not changed it is still "imageHolder" only.

Yes I have confirmed it by coping and pasting your code on my local visual studio and tried this issue.
Issue was reproducible on my local environment as well.

Solution was very simple as I mention above you have to just use 'imageHolder' instead of 'phForChildPage_imageHolder'.

Update your javascript code

```
$(function () {
$("#phForChildPage_fuUserPicture").on('change', function () {
    if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
        var imageHolder = $("#phForChildPage_imageHolder");
        imageHolder.empty();
        //make new instance of file reader
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $("<img />", {
                "src": e.target.result,
                "class": "thumb-image",
                "width": "200px",
                "height": "200px"
            }).appendTo(imageHolder);
        }
        imageHolder.show();
        reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[0]);
    }
    else {
        alert("This browser does not support File Reader");
    }
})
});
```

with

```
$(function () {
$("#phForChildPage_fuUserPicture").on('change', function () {
    if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
        var imageHolder = $("#imageHolder");
        imageHolder.empty();
        //make new instance of file reader
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $("<img />", {
                "src": e.target.result,
                "class": "thumb-image",
                "width": "200px",
                "height": "200px"
            }).appendTo(imageHolder);
        }
        imageHolder.show();
        reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[0]);
    }
    else {
        alert("This browser does not support File Reader");
    }
})
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Nitin, but can you please also tell me the reason why div id is not changed. And why `FileUpload` control id is changed. As I am internee and very confused when I used simple `imageHolder` and when I used `phForChildPage_imageHolder`

Comment: Div is not an ASP.Net element, you have not added runat="server". If you don't add runat="server" it becomes just a HTML element and HTML elements id doesn't get changed if event they are in child pages.

Answer (score 0):

I delete my JavaScript code from separate file and put the code in child page under head and call `onchange(this)` function from `asp:FileUpload` control.

```
<asp:TableRow runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                    <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fuUserPicture" onchange="ShowImagePreview(this)" CssClass="ui-corner-all" />
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                        <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imageHolder" Height="150px" Width="240px" />
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
```

And instead of using `<div id=imageHolder></div>` I used `asp:Image` control.

And finally JavaScript code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowImagePreview(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#<%=imageHolder.ClientID%>').prop('src', e.target.result)
                .width(240)
                .height(150);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

And it works fine. But till yet I don't know why it doesn't work when I put this code in separate javascript file and use `#contentPlaceHolderId_controlId` instead of `#controlId` also don't understand why we use `ClientId`. But it works and I am happy. If some one know conceptual answer of above questions please comment. Thanks

Comment: I have found the mistake in your original and updated my answer. Hope that helps you.